# Knex not properly escaping raw postgres queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, escaping, full-text-search, knex.js

I am using Knex (with typescript) to try to query a postgres database. My database table `products` has a column `name` that I want to search through as the user types into a search box. For example, a query of just the letter 'p' should return all products with a name that contains a word that begins with 'p'. For this, I am using the `ts_vector` and `ts_query` functions. My query looks like this:

```
const query = ... // got from user input
const result = await knex(knex.raw('products'))
  .whereRaw(`to_tsvector(name) @@ to_tsquery('?:*')`, query)
  .select('*')
```

When I run this query, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled error { error: select * from products where to_tsvector(name) @@ to_tsquery('$1:*') - bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0
```

If I replace the `whereRaw` line with: `` .whereRaw(`to_tsvector(name) @@ to_tsquery('p:*')`) ``, it correctly runs the query, selecting products whose names contain words beginning with a P.

It seems like there is some conflict with the postgres syntax and knex's raw queries. I want to use a raw query over using `` `${query}:*` `` because I want my inputs to be sanitized and protected from SQL injection. How can I get Knex to properly escape this?

I have tried various combinations of quotes, slashes and colons, but none seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't process placeholders when they are inside quotes (and I am a little surprised that knex does).

You need to do the concatenation explicitly, either inside PostgreSQL:

```
.whereRaw(`to_tsvector(name) @@ to_tsquery(? ||':*')`,query)
```

Or inside typescript:

```
.whereRaw(`to_tsvector(name) @@ to_tsquery(?)`, query+":*")
```

Comment: Knex doesn't know anything about inserted SQL (it doesn't have SQL parser) so there is no way for knex to know if something is inside quotes (even just parsing quotes in a robust manner is not so trivial as one could think).